# Plotly: How to Adjust Histogram Bin Size with Slider?

Tags: python, plotly

Currently using Plotly to display histogram data.  I'd like to be able to implement a slider to be able to change the bin-size of my histogram data and update my plot.  Any idea how I'd do this?

I've attached my function below which successfully displays my data to a url.

```
def displayHistogram(dataSet, sensorNameSet, chartTitle, yAxisTitle, url):
    j = 0
    data = []
    nbins = 1
    for i in dataSet:
        print(i[0][:])
        trace = go.Histogram(x=i[0][:], y=(i[2][:] ), name=sensorNameSet[j], nbinsx=nbins)
        data.append(trace)
        j += 1

    layout = go.Layout(
        title=go.layout.Title(
            text=chartTitle,
            xref='paper',
            x=0
        ),

        yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(
            title=go.layout.yaxis.Title(
                text=yAxisTitle,
                font=dict(
                    family='Courier New, monospace',
                    size=18,
                    color='#7f7f7f'
                )
            )
        )

    )

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    ply.plot(fig, filename=url)
```

Comment: By any chance, did you find a solution to this?